# Amplifier Transfer Function Question

Tags: amplifier

[image]

Hi, this is from Razavi's Analog CMOS IC Design book (2nd edition) - Pg 49.
He says that " We observe that the circuit provides a gain of about 3 in the input range of 0.4V to 0.6V"

But if you look at the graph, at the input of 0.5V, the output voltage is approx 0.55V. 0.55/0.5 = 1.1. **Where is he getting the gain of 3?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is talking about *small-signal* gain, not large-signal. A small change in the input of 0.01V will change the output by about 0.03V. Although it's actually a negative gain here, as an increase in the input means a decrease in the output.

This is an estimate, though; just visually looking at the graph I would estimate a gain more around -2.5 or perhaps a bit more, probably lower magnitude than the 3 stated in the text.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind just explaining a bit more on differential gain. I usually thought that was in reference to differential amplifiers? How exactly is this differential gain?

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong term there. Early-morning sloppiness. Fixed it.

Comment: That makes more sense now. Small-Signal gain is the derivative of large signal gain (slope) in the linear region of an amp.

Comment: @Hearth -- in some universe it's called differential gain.  *I* knew what you meant, but from context, not from the word you used.

Comment: @TimWescott Mornings tend to make me even worse with words than I normally am!

Answer (score 0):

The gain comes from the small-signal gain, first you have to bias (put a dc voltage into) \$V_{in}\$ so that the \$|\frac{d}{dV_{in}}V_{out}|\$ is big, in a simpler way, use a \$V_{in}\$ that is located at a very steep position of the graph. In the example the author mentions

> input in the range of 0.4V and 0.6V.

Lets use \$V_{in}=0.5V\$, at the very center of the range he suggests (that leads to \$V_{out} \approx 0.55)\$.

Now, if you have a signal added to that constant part, say, \$V_{in}=0.5+0.1\$, the output is \$V_{out} \approx 0.3 = 0.55 - 0.25\$.

From this, it can be determined that \$\frac{d}{dV_{in}}V_{out} \approx -0.25/0.1 = -2.5\$ if you bias \$V_{in}\$ with 0.5V. This gives you the gain for small signals applied to device while biased.

Remember that, by the first terms of the Taylor series
$$f(x_0+\delta x) \approx f(x_0) + \frac{d}{dx}f(x_0)\delta x$$

So,

$$V_{out}(0.5+\delta x) \approx V_{out}(0.5) -2.5 \cdot \delta x = 0.55 -2.5 \delta x $$

> Where is he getting the gain of 3?

The author approximated 2.5 to 3 and ignored the fact that this device is an inverting amplifier (has a **negative** gain of 2.5, which is almost 3).